# How do I flip a bit in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to perform a bitwise NOT in SQL Server. I'd like to do something like this:

```
update foo
set Sync = NOT @IsNew
```

Note: I started writing this and found out the answer to my own question before I finished. I still wanted to share with the community, since this piece of documentation was lacking on MSDN (until I added it to the Community Content there, too).

Comment: I read this wrong I think...was gonna tell you that you can't make a Uturn in SQL Server...:P

Comment: Another article: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/how-to-flip-a-bit-in-sql-server-by-using

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Yes, the ~ operator will work.

```
update foo
set Sync = ~@IsNew
```

Answer (score 35):

**Bitwise NOT: ~**

Bitwise AND: &

Bitwise OR:  |

Bitwise XOR: ^

Answer (score 12):

Lacking on MSDN?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468(SQL.90).aspx

> ~: Performs a bitwise logical NOT operation on an integer value.
>   The ~ bitwise operator performs a bitwise logical NOT for the expression, taking each bit in turn. If expression has a value of 0, the bits in the result set are set to 1; otherwise, the bit in the result is cleared to a value of 0. In other words, ones are changed to zeros and zeros are changed to ones.

Comment: D'oh. I just looked under bitwise operators and ~ unary operators :)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness:

```
SELECT b, 1 - b
FROM
  (SELECT cast(1 AS BIT) AS b
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cast(0 AS BIT) AS b) sampletable
```

Answer (score 2):

~ operator will work only with BIT,

try:
 ~ CAST(@IsNew AS BIT)