# Reverse boolean (bit) value in SQL CE select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to write a query that gets table information from a `SQL CE` database, ready to be put in c#, later to be exported to XML. I need one of the columns to be named 'IDENT' with a boolean value (to represent whether or not it is the identity column, obviously).

For this, I am checking if the AUTOINC_SEED column is null, as follows:

`select isnull(AUTOINC_SEED) as IDENT from information_schema.columns`

However, this returns TRUE for non-identity columns and FALSE for identity columns! Is there any way to reverse the boolean value inside the select statement?

Edit: I'm aware I could do a case statement to solve this particular problem, but it got me curious about inverting boolean (bit) values in SQL.

Comment: Did you try my SQL Server Compact scripting API, can get all relevant schema information for you?

Comment: @ErikEJ could you give me a link to it please?

Comment: You can find it at http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The carat (^) in SQL Server is the [bitwise exclusive OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173278%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) operator.

Since `1 ^ 1` equals 0, and `1 ^ 0` equals 1, you can just do:

```
SELECT (1 ^ [YourBitColumn]) as InverseBit
```

I don't have SQL CE handy either, but since SQL CE appears to have this, I believe the following query should do the trick:

```
select (1 ^ AUTOINC_SEED) as IDENT from information_schema.columns
```

Comment: Sorry only just had a chance to try it. Yes the carat worked - although I did have to replace the 1 with a 0 like so `select (0 ^ AUTOINC_SEED) as IDENT`. It wasn't so much that I needed help with this, more that I was curious. It can, after all, be solved with a `case` statement - but thanks for answering the question and satisfying my curiousity!

Comment: looks like tilda does the trick (~) http://stackoverflow.com/a/177893/1579626 See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468.aspx