# How to update bit value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have 2 Column ID Int and IsActive Bit. I want to update bit value.  If bit is true then false and if bit is flase then true.

For This I have used below query and its works fine but is there any other way to do this task.

```
Update  Table_1  set IsActive = Case when IsActive = 0 then 1 Else 0 End
```

Thanks,
Hitesh Paghadal

Comment: I don't think the alternative is all that different.

Comment: What is the problem with your solution ?

Comment: There is no any problem with current solution.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [Boolean 'NOT' in T-SQL not working on 'bit' datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177762/boolean-not-in-t-sql-not-working-on-bit-datatype) which gives the answer "col = ~ col" as the XOR operator - it also illustrates every other method of doing it.